# ImportError: No module named influxdb. Failed to import the required Python library (influxdb)

Tags: python-3.x, ansible, influxdb

I have problem to manage influxdb through ansible using "influxdb_database" module. Even though it printouts error about python dependency, it is failing only when container where ansible playbook runs is run on diff VM from one where influxdb is hosted. I run ansible playbook from docker container, and if I run container on the host where influxdb is installed, it works fine - it is managing to create db. But, when same container (created from same image as one mentioned before) runs on different VM from one where influxdb is hosted, it is failing with error pasted below. So I am confused now with the error about python dependency and do not understand where the problem is.

Ansible playbook:

```
hosts: "tag_deployment_sysmiromis:&tag_service_tick_yes"
  user: centos
  become: yes
 
  tasks:
- name: Install InfluxDB package
  yum: name="influxdb-{{ frame_tick_influxdb_package_version }}" state=present disable_gpg_check=yes
  register: frame_yum_run
  retries: 10
  until: frame_yum_run is success

- name: Restrict InfluxDB user login
  user:
    name: "influxdb"
    group: "influxdb"
    shell: /sbin/nologin

- name: Enable InfluxDB service
  systemd:
    name: influxdb
    enabled: yes
    state: started

- name: Create InfluxDB data directory
  file:
    path: "{{ frame_tick_influxdb_data_directory }}"
    owner: influxdb
    group: influxdb
    state: directory
    mode: 0750

- name: Create database
  influxdb_database:
      hostname: localhost
      database_name: miroslav
```

Ansible log on failed task

```
TASK [Create database] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /app/lib/ansible/playbooks/influx.yml:6
Using module file /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ansible/modules/database/influxdb/influxdb_database.py
Pipelining is enabled.
<10.246.44.196> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: centos
<10.246.44.196> SSH: EXEC ssh -vvv -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="centos"' -o ConnectTimeout=30 -o ControlPath=/root/.ansible/cp/be4c96d801 10.246.44.196 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'sudo -H -S -n  -u root /bin/sh -c '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'echo BECOME-SUCCESS-brzvkupumuacfsjirccgazqszuzzfwwx ; /usr/bin/python'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"' && sleep 0'"'"''
Escalation succeeded
<10.246.44.196> (1, b'\n{"msg": "Failed to import the required Python library (influxdb) on frame-tick10-246-44-196\'s Python /usr/bin/python. Please read module documentation and install in the appropriate location. If the required library is installed, but Ansible is using the wrong Python interpreter, please consult the documentation on ansible_python_interpreter", "failed": true, "exception": "Traceback (most recent call last):\\n  File \\"/tmp/ansible_influxdb_database_payload_IrdxhN/ansible_influxdb_database_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/influxdb.py\\", line 23, in <module>\\n    from influxdb import InfluxDBClient\\nImportError: No module named influxdb\\n", "invocation": {"module_args": {"username": "root", "retries": 3, "use_udp": true, "proxies": {}, "database_name": "miroslav", "hostname": "localhost", "udp_port": 4444, "ssl": false, "state": "present", "timeout": null, "password": "root", "validate_certs": true, "port": 8086}}}\n', b'OpenSSH_8.1p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020\r\ndebug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config\r\ndebug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 10.246.44.196 is address\r\ndebug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master\r\ndebug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug2: mux_client_hello_exchange: master version 4\r\ndebug3: mux_client_forwards: request forwardings: 0 local, 0 remote\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_session: entering\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_alive: entering\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_alive: done pid = 2147\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_session: session request sent\r\ndebug3: mux_client_read_packet: read header failed: Broken pipe\r\ndebug2: Received exit status from master 1\r\n')
<10.246.44.196> Failed to connect to the host via ssh: OpenSSH_8.1p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 10.246.44.196 is address
debug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug2: mux_client_hello_exchange: master version 4
debug3: mux_client_forwards: request forwardings: 0 local, 0 remote
debug3: mux_client_request_session: entering
debug3: mux_client_request_alive: entering
debug3: mux_client_request_alive: done pid = 2147
debug3: mux_client_request_session: session request sent
debug3: mux_client_read_packet: read header failed: Broken pipe
debug2: Received exit status from master 1
The full traceback is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ansible_influxdb_database_payload_IrdxhN/ansible_influxdb_database_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/influxdb.py", line 23, in <module>
    from influxdb import InfluxDBClient
ImportError: No module named influxdb
fatal: [10.246.44.196]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "database_name": "miroslav",
            "hostname": "localhost",
            "password": "root",
            "port": 8086,
            "proxies": {},
            "retries": 3,
            "ssl": false,
            "state": "present",
            "timeout": null,
            "udp_port": 4444,
            "use_udp": true,
            "username": "root",
            "validate_certs": true
        }
    }
}

MSG:

Failed to import the required Python library (influxdb) on frame-tick10-246-44-196's Python /usr/bin/python. Please read module documentation and install in the appropriate location. If the required library is installed, but Ansible is using the wrong Python interpreter, please consult the documentation on ansible_python_interpreter
```

Answer (score 2):

sounds like you're dealing with the same issue as me. I was struggling to find out what was wrong then I read the requirements and saw this. I'm using a newer version of influxdb than this module supports so I get the same error as you

**Requirements**
The below requirements are needed on the host that executes this module.

python >= 2.6

**influxdb >= 0.9 & <= 1.2.4**

requests

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/influxdb_database_module.html

**UPDATE:**

I have been able to find a way to interact with influx DB using the api instead of the modules since they don't work. This involves editing the influxdb.conf to enable using the API

```
 # modifying the influxdb.conf is required to be able to use the influxDB API
- name: Enable http
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/influxdb/influxdb.conf
    regexp: 'Determines whether HTTP endpoint is enabled.'
    line: '  enabled = true'
- name: Enable bind address :8086
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/influxdb/influxdb.conf
    regexp: '# bind-address = ":8086"'
    line: '  bind-address = ":8086"'
- name: Restart influxdb,
  systemd:
    name: influxdb
    state: restarted
- name: Create influxDB database via api
  uri:
    url: "http://localhost:8086/query"
    method: POST
    body: 'q=CREATE DATABASE "grafanadb"'
    body_format: form-urlencoded
- name: create root user in influxdb
  uri:
    url: "http://localhost:8086/query"
    method: POST
    body: "q=CREATE USER user WITH PASSWORD 'pass' WITH ALL PRIVILEGES"
- name: create grafana user in influxdb
  uri:
    url: "http://localhost:8086/query"
    method: POST
    body: "q=CREATE USER grafana WITH PASSWORD 'grafana'"
- name: Grant all privileges to grafana user on grafanadb
  uri:
    url: "http://localhost:8086/query"
    method: POST
    body: "q=GRANT ALL ON grafanadb TO grafana"
    body_format: form-urlencoded
```

Comment: Thank you! Did you make it work for you? What influxdb version did you use?

Comment: I suppose versions from requirements you mentioned refers for host running ansible playbook, right? Not the host where influxdb I want to manage is running?
I have tried to set influxdb version 1.0.2 on host running playbook, but same error. I have also tried with python2.7 and python3.8 running in ansible host (container in my case) and same error again.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get [influxdb_database](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/influxdb_database_module.html#requirements) module working you have to make sure you have [influxdb-python](https://pypi.org/project/influxdb/) installed on your machine. It is also recommended to have influxdb installed as you might want to directly access the database from the command line.

For CentOS7/RHEL7 installations this can be done as follows:

```sh
yum install python-pip
pip install influxdb
```

CentOS8/RHEL8:

```sh
dnf install python3-pip
pip3 install influxdb
```

Note: You have to use a different python version as the default python interpreter is different for CentOS7 and 8. Therefore influxdb_database python interpreter will be different too.

Therefore, the playbook would look something like this:

```yaml
- name: Install applications for CentOS 7
  yum: 
    name:
    - influxdb        
    - python-pip

- name: Install applications for CentOS 8
  yum: 
    name:
    - influxdb        
    - python3-pip

- name: Install required pip packages
  pip:
    name: 
    - influxdb
```

For debian/ubuntu setups you might do the following:

```sh
apt-get install python-influxdb
```

or

```yaml
- name: Install applications for CentOS
  apt: 
    name:
    - python-influxdb
```

If you are trying to connect to a remote InfluxDB you should ensure that you are authenticating over SSL. You have to manually enable this as it is not enabled by default.

This is what a remote influx database creation would thus look like:

```yaml
- name: Create database using custom credentials
  influxdb_database:
      hostname: "{{influxurl}}"
      username: "{{influxusername}}"
      password: "{{influxpassword}}"
      database_name: "{{influxdbv7}}"
      port: "{{influxport}}"
      ssl: yes
      validate_certs: yes
```

Note: I have tested this setup with CentOS7/8. It possibly works fine with Ubuntu/Debian setups too. For some reason CentOS7 required me to disable validate_certs, otherwise it fails. Possibly its a bug.

Tested version:

- Database: InfluxDB version 1.8.3
- Ansible: version 2.9

Answer (score 0):

What I was missing is influxdb installed in targeted host.Once it is installed, influxdb ansible module start working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Also struggled with this issue. Downgrading the  version of the **requests** python package helped me.

> pip install requests==2.6.0

(2.25.1 did not work for me)